# How to add an onclick event to an infowindow in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I working on a personal project.  I have a form in bootstrap.  In the form, a user can click a button and view a google map and select a store.

Everything is working well, except for clicking on the "Select Store" link in the info window.

Here is a link to it:
https://codepen.io/brettdavis4/pen/wraNJV

I've tried this 2 different ways and I haven't had any luck.

When I try it this way, nothing happens when I click on the map:

```
var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" class="mapclick" data-value="test">Select Store</a>';
```

I'm getting an error when I try it this way:

```
var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" onclick="selectstore("test");">Select Store</a>';
```

This is the error, that I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Can someone take a look at the pen and point me in the right direction?

```js
$('#btnClosestBB').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", initialize);

var address = document.getElementById('address').value + ', ' + document.getElementById('city').value + ', ' + document.getElementById('state').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('zip').value;

var stores = [{
    name: 'Greenwood Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.119458,
    lat: 39.629789,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Eastside Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -85.992033,
    lat: 39.773182,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Castleton Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.069270,
    lat: 39.906005,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'Carmel Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.230302,
    lat: 39.934572,
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'North Carmel Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.129277,
    lat: 40.000897,
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Avon Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.339541,
    lat: 39.764612,
    id: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'Lafayette Rd. Best Buy',
    phone: '317-555-1000',
    long: -86.245499,
    lat: 39.839805,
    id: 7
  }
];


function showResult(result) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = result.geometry.location.lng();
}

function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
  // Initialize the Geocoder
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0]);
      }
    });
  }
}

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('latitude').value, document.getElementById('longitude').value);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: center
  });

  var contentString = document.getElementById('name').value,
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
    });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
    //var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" class="mapclick" data-value="test">Select Store</a>';
    var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" onclick="selectstore("test");">Select Store</a>';
    infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString2
      }),
      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i].lat, stores[i].long),
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
      });
    infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
  }
}

$('a.mapclick').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('test');
});

function selectstore(name) {
  console.log(name);
}

//convert address to lat/long
getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address);
```

```css
#latitude {
  display: none;
}

#longitude {
  display: none;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 15px
}

@media (min-width: 992px) .modal-lg {
  width: 1000px;
}

.modal-body {
  height: 400px;
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gm-style-iw+div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://brettdavis4.github.io/udacity_js_design_patterns/final/js/oauth.js"></script>

<script src="https://brettdavis4.github.io/udacity_js_design_patterns/final/js/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCMbcfzQwpyQHGt0LYix-RB0guBH0OOdgg&extension=.js&output=embed&foo=bar.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body role="document">
  <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
    <div id="divform">
      <input type="text" id="latitude" readonly="" />
      <input type="text" id="longitude" readonly="" />

      <form id="frmworkout">



        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>Name:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="name" value="Bankers Life Fieldhouse" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>Street Address:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="address" value="125 S Pennsylvania St" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>City:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="city" value="Indianapolis" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>State:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="state" value="IN" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>Zip Code:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="zip" value="46204" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br/><button id="btnClosestBB" class=".btn-default">Choose a Best Buy Store</button>
        <h4>Best Buy Store Details:</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span>Store Name:</span>
              </span>
              <input id="bbname" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select a store:</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have included double quotes within double quotes. When you have nested quotes, you need to alternate single and double quotes, plus escape then (the backslash before quotes)

replace

```
var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" onclick="selectstore("test");">Select Store</a>';
```

with

```
var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" onclick="selectstore(\'test\');">Select Store</a>';
```